# How to display a user control source code on an .aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ascx

I am trying to build an aspx page that displays a user control along with the code and code behind for the user control. Is there a way to get the code from a user control page and display it?

Comment: built a user control and copy that code and display that too!

Comment: I don't believe so, you would have to store the code as text and display it in a separate control. I think aspx pages are compiled at runtime when they're served to the client, so the code wouldn't be available at that point.

Comment: There is not a way for the .aspx to examine the code behind and output it as text at runtime.  You would simply need to paste the code in a container for client consumption.

Comment: if you can describe it in English, it's almost certain there's a way to do it in code.  The problem is, the problem (as described) doesn't sound useful.  What is the real problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
FileInfo myControl = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath(@"~\test.aspx.cs"));
StreamReader myControlSource = myControl.OpenText();
string myControlSourceHtml = Server.HtmlEncode(myControlSource.ReadToEnd());
```

Put that in a method and then you could point it to any file to get the source code as HTML and then use CSS to style as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Fun with Google:

`<pre>`
`<![CDATA[`

for anything in your .aspx page.

As for a separate code-behind page, you'll have to copy that code and put it into an html tag in yoru aspx page.

Another thing to look at is the `.renderhtml` method some objects have (gridviews, and such).

**EDIT**
There is a VS Power Tools extension you can use (scroll down to 'HTML COPY': http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/ that might work well for this if you use Visual Studio.

Comment: @Sundeep -- you mean like color, indentation and such?  Not necessarily.  You could use an image.  Or you could use an HTML-enabled textbox (there are a lot of free ones out there, and some nice pay ones as well) if you wanted to try to simulate what the VS look-and-feel was.

Comment: Not necessarily colors, if say code is int i = 0; var j=i+1, copying is not easy. I mean it needs to be converted to "int i=0;<br/>var j=i+1" to showup in aspx page directly or any HTML editor.

Comment: !Sundeep -- I see what you're saying.  I've updated my answer -- take a look.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to create a handler that would read .ASCX, .ASPX or C# page and to display the contents. Have a look at this article on MSDN on [Serving Dynamic Content with HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx)